# How decode JSON response in Javascript from PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a JSON in PHP

```
  http_response_code(400);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $myObj = array('msg' => "Not a valid email address"); 
  echo json_encode($myObj);
  exit();
```

Now I want to decode it in to my response from an ajax PUT

```
var booking_Data = JSON.stringify(bookingData);
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: serverip+"/create/job",
    data: booking_Data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    ...
      statusCode: {
      ...
      400: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      alert(data['msg']);
      alert('400');
      },
```

But the alert returns undefined. The `console.log` of `data`  shows

```
responseJSON : {msg: "Not a valid email address"}
responseText :"{"msg":"Not a valid email address"}"
```

the data is PUT'ing ok and getting a JSON response but can't seem to pick off the `msg`.

Comment: If `console.log(data)` outputs the two lines that you showed in the question then wouldn't you need to say `data.responseJSON.msg`?

Comment: @adrianj98 The JSON is getting generated just fine.  It's also being parsed, as expected.

Comment: responseJSON looks like what you want

Comment: @nnnnnn yes that seems to work, but from examples, I have seen this method has not been used. Thanks